# SmartGwt :Exception while adding button to listgrid using canvas

Tags: smartgwt

I am using smartgwt2.4 and i have listgrid in which i am adding button dynamically using canvas.it is working fine but giving an exception.It fires exception when ListGrid.setData(record)is called.Stacktrace is  as follows..

```
com.smartgwt.client.core.JsObject$SGWT_WARN: 12:15:12.808:WARN:Button:isc_Button_0:ignoring bad or negative top: NaN [enable 'sizing' log for stack trace]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:105)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:157)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannel.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannel.java:1713)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:165)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:120)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:507)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeVoid(ModuleSpace.java:284)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeVoid(JavaScriptHost.java:107)
    at com.smartgwt.client.widgets.BaseWidget.setProperty(BaseWidget.java)
    at com.smartgwt.client.widgets.BaseWidget.setAttribute(BaseWidget.java:628)
    at com.smartgwt.client.widgets.grid.ListGrid.setData(ListGrid.java:9621)
    at com.prolinkdpocadmin.client.widgets.DeduplicationContentGrid.fillGridFromJson(DeduplicationContentGrid.java:213)
    at com.prolinkdpocadmin.client.widgets.DeduplicationContainer.setDataInGrid(DeduplicationContainer.java:104)
    at com.prolinkdpocadmin.client.widgets.DeduplicationContainer.access$0(DeduplicationContainer.java:101)
    at com.prolinkdpocadmin.client.widgets.DeduplicationContainer$1.onSuccess(DeduplicationContainer.java:46)
    at com.prolinkdpocadmin.client.widgets.DeduplicationContainer$1.onSuccess(DeduplicationContainer.java:1)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:216)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:287)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:393)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor15.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:157)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannel.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannel.java:1713)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:165)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:120)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:507)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:264)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:188)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:157)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannel.reactToMessages(BrowserChannel.java:1668)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:401)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:222)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Please help me out.....

This is the code showing how i am using canvas for adding button in to grid ..and all propeties set for listgrid and listGridField...............

lgfprimaryCompanyName = new ListGridField("pCompany", "Primary Company");
        lgfprimaryCompanyName.setWidth(250);
        lgfprimaryCompanyName.setAlign(Alignment.LEFT);

```
    lgfmarkPrimaryAsDuplicate = new ListGridField("MarkPrimaryDuplicate", "Mark As Duplicate");
    lgfmarkPrimaryAsDuplicate.setWidth(130);
    lgfmarkPrimaryAsDuplicate.setCanSort(false);
    lgfmarkPrimaryAsDuplicate.setAlign(Alignment.CENTER);

   // lgfmarkPrimaryAsDuplicate.addRecordClickHandler(this);

    lgfduplicateCompanyName = new ListGridField("dCompany", "Duplicate Company");
    lgfduplicateCompanyName.setWidth(250);
    lgfduplicateCompanyName.setAlign(Alignment.LEFT);

    lgfmarkDuplicateAsDuplicate = new ListGridField("MarkDuplicateDuplicate", "Mark as Duplicate");
    lgfmarkDuplicateAsDuplicate.setWidth(130);
    lgfmarkDuplicateAsDuplicate.setCanSort(false);
    lgfmarkDuplicateAsDuplicate.setAlign(Alignment.CENTER);

   // lgfmarkDuplicateAsDuplicate.addRecordClickHandler(this);

    lgDuplicateCompany = new ListGrid() {

                @Override
                protected Canvas createRecordComponent(final ListGridRecord record, Integer colNum) {

                    String fieldName = this.getFieldName(colNum);
                    if (fieldName.equals("MarkPrimaryDuplicate")) {
                        Button btnMarkPrimaryAsDuplicate = new Button();
                        btnMarkPrimaryAsDuplicate.setTitle("" + record.getAttribute("MarkPrimaryDuplicate"));
                        btnMarkPrimaryAsDuplicate.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                              Window.alert("button in column 2 is clicked");

                                    }
                                }

                            }

                        });
                        return btnMarkPrimaryAsDuplicate;

                    } else if (fieldName.equals("MarkDuplicateDuplicate")) {
                        Button btnMarkDuplicateAsDuplicate = new Button();
                        btnMarkDuplicateAsDuplicate.setTitle("" + record.getAttribute("MarkDuplicateDuplicate"));
                        btnMarkDuplicateAsDuplicate.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                             Window.alert("button in column 4 is clicked");

    }
                        });

                        return btnMarkDuplicateAsDuplicate;

                    } else {
                        return null;
                    }
                }

    };
    lgDuplicateCompany.setFields(lgfprimaryCompanyName, lgfmarkPrimaryAsDuplicate, lgfduplicateCompanyName, lgfmarkDuplicateAsDuplicate);
    lgDuplicateCompany.setWidth(780);
    lgDuplicateCompany.setSelectionType(SelectionStyle.SINGLE);
    lgDuplicateCompany.setSelectionAppearance(SelectionAppearance.ROW_STYLE);
    lgDuplicateCompany.setCanResizeFields(true);
    lgDuplicateCompany.setCanReorderFields(true);
    lgDuplicateCompany.setShowRecordComponents(true);
    lgDuplicateCompany.setShowRecordComponentsByCell(true);
```

Comment: I have posted the code... There are two async calls on button click..1.One is for marking that company as duplicate ..2.to fetch the the updates data and again fill ListGrid with modified data..

Answer (score 0):

are you using AutoFitData and also specifying a specific width? I believe those conflicting settings would give you this error.

Comment: I am setting width just for listGrid and ListGridFields...and it is necessary to set it...i am not getting why it is firing exception???